# How do I add inline JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: 8, javascript

```js
$hide_submit_settings = array('hide_submit' => array(
  'hide_submit_status' => variable_get('hide_submit_status', TRUE),
  'hide_submit_method' => variable_get('hide_submit_method', 'disable'),
  'hide_submit_css' => variable_get('hide_submit_css', 'hide-submit-disable'),
  'hide_submit_abtext' => t(variable_get('hide_submit_abtext', '')),
  'hide_submit_atext' => t(variable_get('hide_submit_atext', '')),
  'hide_submit_hide_css' => variable_get('hide_submit_hide_css', 'hide-submit-processing'),
  'hide_submit_hide_text' => t(variable_get('hide_submit_hide_text', 'Processing...')),
  'hide_submit_indicator_style' => t(variable_get('hide_submit_indicator_style', 'expand-left')),
  'hide_submit_spinner_color' => t(variable_get('hide_submit_spinner_color', '#000')),
  'hide_submit_spinner_lines' => (int)variable_get('hide_submit_spinner_lines', 12),
  'hide_submit_hide_fx' => t(variable_get('hide_submit_hide_fx', FALSE)),
  'hide_submit_reset_time' => (int)variable_get('hide_submit_reset_time', 5000),
);

drupal_add_js($hide_submit_settings, 'setting');
```

How do I use it in Drupal 8?

Comment: This is no longer supported. Every CSS or JS have to be a physical file and defined as library. If you need some dynamic interactions with JS, use drupalSettings in #attach attribute and access them in your JS file.

Comment: I can't see the reason why people vote down this question.

Comment: I didn't vote on this question, but it seems that the attached code is for drupal settings not inline JavaScript. It is still possible to attach drupal settings as @Ivan Jaros mentions.

Comment: I would expect the question was voted down because there was no actual question. Just some code and a question "how to do this in Drupal 8?" That makes this a bad question because if someone doesn't know what that code is doing they cannot answer the question even if then know how to do this in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this article, how you can adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module:

https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/assets

Comment: Would be good to include a relevant example snippet from there (drupalSettings)

Comment: There is no relevat information about adding inline css on that page.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom hook_theme twig file for adding CSS and JS

```
function mymodule_theme() {
    return [
        'css' => [
            'render element' => 'children',
            'variables' => array(
                'cssdata' => NULL,
            ),
        ],
        'js' => [
            'render element' => 'children',
            'variables' => array(
                'jsdata' => NULL,
            ),
        ],
    ];
}
```

**js.html.twig**

```
<style>{{ cssdata }}</style>
```

**js.html.twig**

```
<script>{{ jsdata}}</script>
```

**In render array.**

```
$output[] = [

'#theme' => 'js',

'#jsdata' => 'alert("Hello World")',

];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: this may have security implications, make fully sure the $criticalCss variable contains *only* css you trust.

Just leaving a useful snippet related to inline CSS that needs to be added in <head>; it can be done like this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    // **WARNING**: make sure critical.css is safe (e.g. written/generated by you).
    $criticalCss = file_get_contents('path/to/critical.css');
    $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
    [
        '#tag' => 'style',
        '#value' => Markup::create($criticalCss),
    ],
    'critical-css',
  ];

}
```

This snippet was adapted from critical_css.module: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/critical_css/blob/8.x-1.x/critical_css.module