# Old GZ file is generated after editing CSS original

Tags: 8, theming, css-js-aggregation

After editing CSS file in the `/sites/default/files/css` directory I removed its GZ version and it's generated after a while, but with old CSS code.

How to edit CSS correctly? And how to force generating GZ immediately after editing CSS?

ps. Drupal 8.7.3

Comment: You add custom CSS from either a custom theme or a custom module. What's inside sites/default/files is content, lives outside VCS and is managed by Drupal. Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme and https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-module or try the [CSS Editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_editor) module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add inline JavaScript and CSS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206208/how-do-i-add-inline-javascript-and-css)